# Workfront REST API BAD request

Tags: rest, attask, workfront-api

I'm trying to send a basic search request, but it's returning bad request. It only does it for some objects. I had similar problems before, but once I changed the version on my request string some objects worked fine. Does anyone know if these objects are restricted or something?

Request sent:

```
https://company.attask.com/attask/api/v5.0/arvstp/search - BAD REQUEST
https://company.attask.com/attask/api/v5.0/arvsts/search - BAD REQUEST
```

Objects:
Approval Step -- arvstp

Approver Status -- arvsts

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a bad request because the objects you are searching for are not top level objects which means they are actually child objects to another Object and cannot be searched.

Approval step is a child object to approvals so to search you would do the following call.

```
attask/api/v5.0/ARVPTH/search?fields=approvalSteps
```

you can tell if an object is searchable by navigating to our API explorer

https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/api-explorer/

and under the object you are interested in select the Search tab if there is no data then the object cannot be searched.

Comment: Do you know how to access those objects, the top level objects? I tried accessing the low level objects like your example, but it did not work for me. Also, the search tab idea is not always correct, take approval path, the search tab is empty, but I'm still able to search through all its fields.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try my example?

Comment: I think I figured it out! I believe you were just missing the `:*` at the end. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if the model what you are passing in your search request matches with the saver side mapping of the code. e.g.

lets say you are passing `{"searchString":"Google","totalResults":100, "otherKeywords" : ["hello","engine"]}` to rest search request, then your serer side code should also have exact matching domain with the same name and object type. for example in case you are using java jersey in server side then you need to have a class with the same name matching domain. remember array should be mapped to List, not to any random object.